# About a set that is continuous image of a measurable set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is my first post. I hope that you can help me with a little hint. My problem says: If $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $S^2$ is defined to be $S^2=\{s^2\ |\ s\in S \}$.Show that if $\lambda(S)=0$, then $\lambda(S^2)=0$, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure.

I can prove measurability of $S^2$, but I can´t prove $\lambda(S^2)=0$. Can you give me any hint?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! +1 for formatting the question well in the first post itself!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Actually if $f\in C^1(\mathbb R),$ then $m(S)=0\implies m(f(S))=0$ and the general result is no harder to prove. For the proof, WLOG $S\subset [-a,a]$ for some $a>0.$ Use the boundedness of $f'$ on $[-a,a]$ to show there is $C$ such that $m(f(I)) \le Cm(I)$ for each interval $I\subset [-a,a].$ Therefore ...

Comment: Hi zhw. Thank's for your answer. Can you explain me what does it mean WLOGS?

Comment: WLOG $S$ is what I wrote. WLOG = without loss of generality.

Comment: Thank you zhw. I will try with your hint.